# nuxt, ошибка [vuex] duplicate namespace auth/ for the namespaced module auth

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

вот такая ошибка в приложении [vuex] duplicate namespace auth/ for the namespaced module auth. Возникла при создании файла user.js в /plugins/mixins, с кодом :

```
`import Vue from 'vue';

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

const Validation = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.mixin({
            computed: {
                ...mapGetters({
                    user: 'auth/user',
                    authenticated: 'auth/authenticated'
                })
            }    
        })
    }
};

Vue.use(Validation);`
```

Если знаете как решить буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже сталкивался подобной проблемой. 
Скорее всего у Вас имеется файл `auth.js`, а каждый файл преобразуется в модуль пространства имён.
Чтобы постараться решить данный вопрос попробуйте перенести логику в папку с модулями и написать следующее решение:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

    const User = {
        install(Vue, options) {
            Vue.mixin({
                computed: {
                    ...mapGetters({
                        user: 'user',
                        authenticated: 'authenticated'
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    };

    Vue.use(User);
```

Дополнение:

Нашёл ещё подобный вопрос на английской части форума. 
Можете посмотреть [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338642/duplicate-namespace-auth-for-the-namespaced-module-auth)

Comment: Сделал как тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338642/duplicate-namespace-auth-for-the-namespaced-module-auth. Ошибка пропала, но теперь при авторизации отправка на сервер идёт и ответ получается правильный(с токеном и т.д.) но авторизация на клиенте не происходит. Ошибок никаких нет, как вы думаете с чем это может быть связано?