# nuxt, как правильно связать два select

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

есть первый select, который использует данные Стран, как сделать так что бы при выборе страны в перво select, данные городов для данной страны подгружались во второй select. Два массива с странами и городами есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать параметры `list` привязав к ним названия Стран и списков городов.
Вот условный пример:

```js
    let CitiesRussia =[ //Ваш список городов в одной стране
        {name:'Москва'},
        {name:'Санкт-Петербург'},
        {name:'Нижний Новгород'},
        {name:'Вогоград'}
    ];
    let CitiesUSA =[ //Ваш список городов в второй стране
        {name:'New-York'},
        {name:'San Francisco'},
        {name:'Roseville'},
        {name:'Pasadena'}
    ];
    let CitiesFrance =[ //Ваш список городов в третьей стране
        {name:'Paris'},
        {name:'Versailles'},
        {name:'Dijon'},
        {name:'Lille'}
    ];
    let CitiesGermany =[ //Ваш список городов в четвёртой стране
        {name:'Berlin'},
        {name:'Bavaria'},
        {name:'Hamburg'},
        {name:'Hesse'}
    ];
    let Arr ={
        'Russia': CitiesRussia,
        'USA': CitiesUSA,
        'France': CitiesFrance,
        'Germany': CitiesGermany,
    };

    new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        data: {
            firstOption: null,
            secondOption: null,
            list: Arr
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <select v-model="firstOption">
        <option v-for="(item, index) in list">{{ index }}</option>
    </select>
    <select v-model="secondOption" v-if="firstOption">
        <option v-for="option in list[firstOption]" value="option.name">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли. Не могли бы посмотреть это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076411/nuxt-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-vuex-duplicate-namespace-auth-for-the-namespaced-module-auth